# More precise word or phrase for neutral connotation of racism

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, synonyms, connotation, nonsubjective

[Racism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/racism) in the dictionary means

> a belief or doctrine that inherent differences among the various human races determine cultural or individual achievement, usually involving the idea that one's own race is superior and has the right to rule others.

Is there a word or phrase that means

> a belief or doctrine that inherent differences among the various human races determine cultural or individual achievement

**without** implying "the idea that one's own race is superior and has the right to rule others"?

None of the other answers are relevant.

Comment: What does  “None of the other answers are relevant” mean?

Comment: *Raciality* recognizes "inherent differences among the various human races" **and** stops there.

Comment: @jwpat7 The related answers, for example, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91540/is-there-a-word-or-short-phrase-to-indicate-the-opposite-extreme-of-racism?rq=1, does not address this question. There are only a few search results for 'racism' and nothing specifically answers this question.

Comment: @Kris Interesting, but I can't find a definition for raciality. Webster's wanted a subscription no less! It turns red in my spell checker.

Comment: Chloe, [Varieties of racism](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/106065) may be relevant

Comment: @jwpat7 I saw that too, but each of those varieties seeks to do harm to another race with implying one's own race should rule over the victim.

Comment: You're right, it's not recognized by many dictionaries. Those that do, do not get into much detail. You can see usage examples, though.

Comment: I think the part you want to have automatically implies the part you don't want to imply. It's in its nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Raciality* recognizes "inherent differences among the various human races" and stops there.

A citation that may be relevant to explain the usage of *raciality* [emphasis mine]:

> … raciation and **raciality**  are important and unavoidable social facts. They describe the way people's racial histories and identities inform how they "organize meaningfully, give order to, and thus define and construct the worlds in which we live, our life-words (Outlaw, 1996, p.5). Raciality, ethinicity, and gender "are constitutive of the personal and social being of persons … they make up the historically mediated structural features of human life-worlds and inform lived experience" (p.174)
>   …
>   Outlaw emphasizes that **raciality is a postive phenomenon**, and he stresses that "racialism neither is nor need become racism" (1996, p.8)
>   …
>   Racism comprises "sets of beliefs, images and practices that are 'imbued with negative valuation' and employed as modes of exclusion, inferiorization, subordination, and exploitation in order to deny targeted racial or ethnic groups full participation in the social, political, economic, and cultural life of a political community" (p.8)
>   Racialism is the positive recognition of how the constitute features of one's lifeworld, one's personality and sense of historical and cultural identitiy, comprise a set of preconscious filters and assumptions that frame how life is felt and lived. Racialism's valuation is positive, not negative. … **We can celebrate the constitutive elements of our and others' raciality in a way imbued with generosity and recognition** quite different from the brutal, negative celebration of one's racism.

Stephen Brookfield: *The Power of Critical Theory for Adult Learning And Teaching,* [p.281-282 (GoogleBooks)](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=EEyI8f4ZmdUC&pg=PA281&dq=%22raciality%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cqapUfGoFIX_4AOmzYEo&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22raciality%22&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

Consider [***racialism***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racialism#Definitions_and_differences)

> "*'Racism' implies a presumption of racial superiority and a harmful intent, whereas advocates of positive racial differences use the word 'racialism' to indicate a strong interest in matters of race without the presumption of superiority or the desire to cause harm to others*."

Comment: Racialism is defined in the [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/157084?redirectedFrom=racialism#eid) as `another term for racism`. I think people would be confused by that.

Answer (score 0):

<del>A little too specific maybe, but: genetic determinism?</del>

After a little research, it seems that [biological determinism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_determinism) fits better:

> Biological determination (also biologism) is the interpretation of
>   humans and human life from a strictly biological point of view, and it
>   is closely related to genetic determinism. Another definition is that
>   biological determinism is the hypothesis that biological factors such
>   as an organism's individual genes (as opposed to social or
>   environmental factors) completely determine how a system behaves or
>   changes over time.

Comment: How do you define that? Why do you think it fits? Who has used the expression to what effect, where, when? I will deem this an answer only then and only then shall I up vote. Lol.

Comment: Interesting, but 'determinism' might imply predestination, or lack of free will. If discussing a negative attribute, this will surely have a negative connotation. Perhaps there is a term for 'different' but neutral. I believe there may be no such term in English.